# Why is bash's prompt variable called PS1?

Tags: bash, command-line

The environment variable for the bash prompt is called `PS1` (usually set in ~/.bashrc). What does PS1 stand for? Is there a PS2?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

PS1 stands for "Prompt String One" or "Prompt Statement One", the first prompt string (that you see at a command line).

Yes, there is a PS2 and more! Please read [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-take-control-of-ps1-ps2-ps3-ps4-and-prompt_command/) article and the Arch [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt) and of course [The Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html).

Answer (score 31):

from slightly paraphrased from [The Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)

PS1
The primary prompt string. The default value is ‘\s-\v\$ ’.

PS2
The secondary prompt string.  ie for continued commands (those taking more than one line). The default value is ‘> ’.

PS3
The value of this variable is used as the prompt for the select command. ie for input into a running script. If this variable is not set, the select command prompts with ‘#? ’.

PS4
The value is the prompt printed before the command line is echoed when the -x option is set. The first character of PS4 is replicated multiple times, as necessary, to indicate multiple levels of indirection. The default is ‘+ ’.

PS1 and PS2 are from the original sh,  PS3 and PS4 were added as part of bash

See examples [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-take-control-of-ps1-ps2-ps3-ps4-and-prompt_command/)